# What tense do I use for different actions in the past for dead people?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, perfect-aspect, past-habitual

I want to refer to 2 kids and draw some parallelisms. John is alive now. Mark is dead.

John lives in New York.  "Mark LIVED in New York" or "Mark USED TO LIVE in New York".

John likes to play soccer.  Mark LIKED or USED TO LIKE playing soccer?

Comment: Both use past tense (lived *vs* used to).

Comment: Are you by chance try­ing to fig­ure how whether there are par­tic­u­lar “rules” for how to trans­late the many and var­i­ous Span­ish past tenses like the *pre­té­rito de­fi­nido* (p.ej. *ha­bló, dijo*) ver­sus the *pre­té­rito im­per­fecto* (p.ej. *ha­blaba, de­cía*) into cor­re­spond­ing English tenses to con­vey the same mean­ing? Not to men­tion the cor­re­spond­ing com­pound tenses us­ing in­flec­tions of *ha­ber* “have” + past par­tici­ple, let alone the cor­re­spond­ing sub­junc­tives for all these.

Answer (score 1):

"Mark **used to live** in New York" implies Mark lived there and now doesn't, but he **might** **still** **live**, though not particularly in New York.

"Mark **lived** in New York" is, in my opinion, more suitable when talking about a dead person.

However, if you **state** that Mark is dead before writing where he lived, then you can say "used to". Otherwise, you might make the reader confused (in terms of Mark's situation - being dead).

> E.g.: "Mark died a week ago. [blah-blah-blah]. He was a smart guy, used to play soccer(,) and lived in New York."